# How to properly start a PostgreSQL instance in Docker?

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile

I'm new to PostgreSQL but I want to run a PostgreSQL instance in Docker, along with my program which will communicate with it.
My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM archlinux:latest
RUN pacman --sync -yu --noconfirm --needed base-devel curl postgresql postgresql-libs jansson

WORKDIR /srv

COPY main3.c /srv/

RUN gcc main3.c -lpq -ljansson -std=c99 -I/usr/include/postgresql
RUN su postgres -c 'initdb --locale=C.UTF-8 --encoding=UTF8 -D /var/lib/postgres/data --data-checksums'
RUN mkdir /run/postgresql
RUN chown postgres: /run/postgresql
RUN su postgres -c 'postgres -D /var/lib/postgres/data' &

EXPOSE 5432
EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 45510

CMD ["./a.out"]
```

Then I build it with `docker build -t myexample .` and run it with `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8000:8000 -e DATABASE_HOST=127.0.0.1 -e DATABASE_PORT=5432 -e DATABASE_NAME=mydb -e DATABASE_USER=ene -e DATABASE_PASSWORD=as_shrimple_as_that myexample`. These variables must be passed from outside since they will be different for other people who would run the docker image.

However, I get an error as the output:

```
connection to database failed: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Here is a piece of my code that checks for the database connection.

```
...
char* db_host = getenv("DATABASE_HOST");
char* db_port = getenv("DATABASE_PORT");
char* db_name = getenv("DATABASE_NAME");
char* db_user = getenv("DATABASE_USER");
char* db_password = getenv("DATABASE_PASSWORD");

char conninfo[256];
sprintf(conninfo, "host=%s port=%s dbname=%s user=%s password=%s", db_host, db_port, db_name, db_user, db_password);
PGconn *conn = PQconnectdb(conninfo);

if (PQstatus(conn) != CONNECTION_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "connection to database failed: %s\n", PQerrorMessage(conn));
    PQfinish(conn);
return 1;
}
...
```

Am I starting the PostgreSQL server improperly or is something about Docker causing it to perish before my program starts?

I don't need to modify the database so far - I just want it to connect. My program will then serve the version data from the database.

Comment: Why don’t you use the standard docker image?

Comment: I've tried that too but I'm getting the same issue about the connection being refused. I picked Arch since I'm more familiar with pacman than apt but in the end it doesn't matter for me what the image is as long as it accomplishes the task.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to run postgres in Docker is to run it in a separate container using the official upstream images rather than trying to run it in the same container as your application.

Typically, you would manage this using a [`docker compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) file, although that is not strictly necessary (`docker compose` is really just a wrapper for `docker run`, so you can accomplish the same thing with multiple `docker run` commands -- it's just not as convenient).

That might look something like the following. You would place this content in a file named `compose.yaml` adjacent to your `Dockerfile`:

```
volumes:
  pg_data:

services:
  postgres:
    image: docker.io/postgres:15
    volumes:
      - "pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ene
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: as_shrimple_as_that

  app:
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      DATABASE_HOST: postgres
      DATABASE_PORT: 5432
      DATABASE_NAME: my_db
      DATABASE_USER: ene
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: as_shrimple_as_that
```

You would probably manage environment variables with a `.env` file rather than including them in the compose file like I've shown here.

You would bring up this environment with `docker compose up`, or `docker compose up -d` to detach from the container consoles.

You would bring it down with `docker compose down`, or `docker compose down -v` to delete the database storage so that you start fresh next time.

---

Looking at your Dockerfile, note that this does not do what you think:

```
RUN su postgres -c 'postgres -D /var/lib/postgres/data' &
```

A `RUN` command runs *only* during the image build process. Processes started by `RUN` are run in an isolated environment and are terminated when the `RUN` command completes. These commands are **not** executed when start a container from the image.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand it a bit more. However in my case the variables must be passed from the `docker run` command, other users will be using it with their own env variables with different names, passwords and ports. Can I somehow accomplish that, even if it's not the best practice?